# How to create a new object as a subset of object properties of any depth, while renaming properties on the fly

Tags: javascript, select, ecmascript-6, nested, object-literal

Although a plethora of posts have been dedicated to the topic, I still couldn't find a satisfying idea how to subset object properties of *any* depth. More so, I would also like to rename the selected keys on the fly.

What I'm aiming to achieve is a generic function, let's call it `select()`, that accepts two inputs:

- an object of data
- an object in which keys represent the desired new name, and values specify the path to desired properties.

For example, consider the following data:

```js
const earthData = {
  distanceFromSun: 149280000,
  continents: {
    asia: {
      area: 44579000,
      population: 4560667108,
      countries: { japan: { temperature: 62.5 } },
    },
    africa: { area: 30370000, population: 1275920972 },
    europe: { area: 10180000, population: 746419440 },
    america: { area: 42549000, population: 964920000 },
    australia: { area: 7690000, population: 25925600 },
    antarctica: { area: 14200000, population: 5000 },
  },
};
```

My goal is to call `select()` this way:

```js
const earthDataSubset = select(earthData, {
  distanceFromSun: ['distanceFromSun'],
  asiaPop: ['continents', 'asia', 'population'],
  americaArea: ['continents', 'america', 'area'],
  japanTemp: ['continents', 'asia', 'countries', 'japan', 'temperature'],
});
```

where the resulted `earthDataSubset` is

```js
// earthDataSubset
{
    distanceFromSun: 149280000,
    asiaPop: 4560667108,
    americaArea: 42549000,
    japanTemp: 62.5
}
```

At this point, one may ask why I don't simply do this:

```js
const earthDataSubsetSimple = {
    distanceFromSun: earthData.distanceFromSun,
    asiaPop: earthData.continents.asia.population,
    americaArea: earthData.continents.america.area,
    japanTemp: earthData.continents.asia.countries.japan.temperature
}
```

This won't work because typically, my data arrives as an *array* of objects, so I need to *map* over the array and apply the same select procedure such as in:

```js
const earthData = {
    distanceFromSun: 149280000,
    continents: {
      asia: {
        area: 44579000,
        population: 4560667108,
        countries: { japan: { temperature: 62.5 } },
      },
      africa: { area: 30370000, population: 1275920972 },
      europe: { area: 10180000, population: 746419440 },
      america: { area: 42549000, population: 964920000 },
      australia: { area: 7690000, population: 25925600 },
      antarctica: { area: 14200000, population: 5000 },
    },
  };

  const earthData2050 = {
    distanceFromSun: 149280000,
    continents: {
      asia: {
        area: 44579000,
        population: 4560767108,
        countries: { japan: { temperature: 73.6 } },
      },
      africa: { area: 30370000, population: 1275960972 },
      europe: { area: 10180000, population: 746419540 },
      america: { area: 42549000, population: 964910000 },
      australia: { area: 7690000, population: 25928600 },
      antarctica: { area: 14200000, population: 5013 },
    },
  };

const myEarthArr = [earthData, earthData2050]
```

Admittedly, I could have called `.map()` array method simply as:

```js
const mapRes = myEarthArr.map((record) => ({
  distanceFromSun: record.distanceFromSun,
  asiaPop: record.continents.asia.population,
  americaArea: record.continents.america.area,
  japanTemp: record.continents.asia.countries.japan.temperature,
}));
```

And get the desired output:

```js
// [ { distanceFromSun: 149280000,
//     asiaPop: 4560667108,
//     americaArea: 42549000,
//     japanTemp: 62.5 },
//   { distanceFromSun: 149280000,
//     asiaPop: 4560767108,
//     americaArea: 42549000,
//     japanTemp: 73.6 } ]
```

**Nevertheless**, I'm looking to create my own *generic* `select()` function that accepts one object, and subsets it. The benefit of such approach is its flexibility. I can use it standalone on a single object, plus allowing me to scale `select()` to an array of objects when needed, by doing something like:

```js
// pseudo code
myEarthArr.map( (record) => select(record, {
  distanceFromSun: ['distanceFromSun'],
  asiaPop: ['continents', 'asia', 'population'],
  americaArea: ['continents', 'america', 'area'],
  japanTemp: ['continents', 'asia', 'countries', 'japan', 'temperature'],
}) )
```

From looking around in StackOverflow posts, I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39680033/6105259) to be the closest. But neither do I understand how to shape it to my needs, nor whether its recursive mechanism actually required in my situation. By contrast, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17781472/6105259) offers a ton of solutions for the simple scenario of subsetting, but none is addressing the issue of nested properties.

Comment: Perhaps [JSONpath](https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base-05.html) is what you're looking for?

Comment: @tromgy, thanks. Not sure I understand how this interacts with JavaScript. Could you demonstrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const select = (data, filters) => Object.entries(filters)
.reduce((res, [key, path]) => {
  return {
   ...res,
   [key]: path.reduce((current, segment) => current[segment] ?? undefined , data)
  }

}, {})
  

const earthData = {
  distanceFromSun: 149280000,
  continents: {
    asia: {
      area: 44579000,
      population: 4560667108,
      countries: { japan: { temperature: 62.5 } },
    },
    africa: { area: 30370000, population: 1275920972 },
    europe: { area: 10180000, population: 746419440 },
    america: { area: 42549000, population: 964920000 },
    australia: { area: 7690000, population: 25925600 },
    antarctica: { area: 14200000, population: 5000 },
  },
};


const earthDataSubset = select(earthData, {
  distanceFromSun: ['distanceFromSun'],
  asiaPop: ['continents', 'asia', 'population'],
  americaArea: ['continents', 'america', 'area'],
  japanTemp: ['continents', 'asia', 'countries', 'japan', 'temperature'],
});

console.log(earthDataSubset)
```

**Explanation inner reduce part**

`path.reduce((current, segment) => current[segment] ?? undefined , data)`

**path** is an array of property nested inside **data**

**path.reduce** cycle all these property name

**example**

`path = ['continents', 'asia', 'population']`

in the first iteration

- current is data your object (I omit it because it's a bit long)
- segment is 'continents'
- return data['continents']

second iteration

- current is data['continents']
- segment is 'asia'
- return data['continents']['asia']

You got the idea

Comment: Awesome! Looks very good and simple.

Comment: @Emman thanks man :) I can add some explanation if you need it

Comment: Thanks, yes I need some explanation, and I can even frame where I struggle to understand. If we define a utility function `const prop = (obj, key) => obj[key] `, and `const somePath = ['continents', 'asia', 'countries', "japan", "temperature"]`. Then `const res = somePath.reduce(prop, earthData)` gives that `res` is `62.5`. **I don't understand how `reduce()` works here**. If you can please explain this, the rest of your solution seems more simple to comprehend.

Comment: @Emman I tried to explain it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it using JSONPath.

Install the [jsonpath-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus) npm package:

```
npm install jsonpath-plus
```

And then you can write your function like this (assuming you're using modules):

```
import { JSONPath } from "jsonpath-plus";

function select(data, query) {
    let result = {};

    for (let key of Object.keys(query)) {
        result[key] = JSONPath(`$.${query[key].join('.')}`, data)[0];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Using your data (`myEarthArr`, which I omit here for brevity) and the query object:

```
const myQuery = {
    distanceFromSun: ['distanceFromSun'],
    asiaPop: ['continents', 'asia', 'population'],
    americaArea: ['continents', 'america', 'area'],
    japanTemp: ['continents', 'asia', 'countries', 'japan', 'temperature'],
};
```

Running this loop:

```
for (let dataItem of myEarthArr) {
    console.log(select(dataItem, myQuery));
}
```

produces:

```
{
  distanceFromSun: 149280000,
  asiaPop: 4560667108,
  americaArea: 42549000,
  japanTemp: 62.5
}
{
  distanceFromSun: 149280000,
  asiaPop: 4560767108,
  americaArea: 42549000,
  japanTemp: 73.6
}
```

Comment: You can simplify it by using actual JSONPath expressions in the query object instead of arrays.