# Building a custom function for creating a new object as a subset of object properties of any depth: how to deal with missing entries?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, option-type

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72058533/6105259), I've built my own custom function that subsets an object, to keep only *some* of its properties. Problem is, the code breaks if I point to a property that doesn't exist.

Essentially, I'm looking to mimic the functionality of the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) , but in the context of my own custom function.

***My current function implementation***

The function accepts two inputs:

1. The object to subset
2. An object that specifies the path of each property we want to keep, as well as a *name* for the key of this value in the new object.

The function's output is a *new* object, which is a subset of the original. By design, this is an immutable implementation.

```js
// typescript
const is = (t: any, T: any) => t?.constructor === T;
const getProp = <T>(obj: any, key: string): T => obj[key] ?? null;
const getValue = <T>(pathToVal: string[], origData: T): T => pathToVal.reduce(getProp, origData);

const select = (data: Object, paths: Record<string, string[]>) =>
    !is(paths, Object) // if `paths` is not object, fail now
        ? new Error('path supplied not an object')
        : // else do what we want
          Object.entries(paths).reduce(
              (res: object, [key, path]: [string, string[]]) => Object.assign(res, { [key]: getValue(path, data) }),
              {}
          );
```

Here is an example how to call `select()`.

```js
const earthData = {
  distanceFromSun: 149280000,
  continents: {
    asia: {
      area: 44579000,
      population: 4560667108,
      countries: { japan: { temperature: 62.5 } },
    },
    africa: { area: 30370000, population: 1275920972 },
    europe: { area: 10180000, population: 746419440 },
    america: { area: 42549000, population: 964920000 },
    australia: { area: 7690000, population: 25925600 },
    antarctica: { area: 14200000, population: 5000 },
  },
};


const earthDataSubset = select(earthData, {
  distanceFromSun: ['distanceFromSun'],
  asiaPop: ['continents', 'asia', 'population'],
  americaArea: ['continents', 'america', 'area'],
  japanTemp: ['continents', 'asia', 'countries', 'japan', 'temperature'],
});

console.log(earthDataSubset)
// { distanceFromSun: 149280000,
//   asiaPop: 4560667108,
//   americaArea: 42549000,
//   japanTemp: 62.5 }
```

***The problem***

Requesting to subset a property that doesn't exist results in an error, instead of simply returning `null` for that non-existing path.

```js
const earthDataSubset2 = select(earthData, {
  distanceFromSun: ["distanceFromSun"],
  asiaPop: ["continents", "asia", "population"],
  americaArea: ["continents", "america", "area"],
  japanTemp: ["continents", "asia", "countries", "japan", "temperature"],
  foo: ["bar", "baz"] // <~~~~ this is the addition that breaks the code
});

console.log(earthDataSubset2)
// Cannot read properties of null (reading 'baz')
```

But what I expect to get is:

```js
// expected output

console.log(earthDataSubset2)
// { distanceFromSun: 149280000,
//   asiaPop: 4560667108,
//   americaArea: 42549000,
//   japanTemp: 62.5,
//   foo: null
}
```

Also please note that if the non-existing property is *at the end* of the path, we do get `null` as expected.

```js
const earthDataSubset3 = select(earthData, {
  distanceFromSun: ["distanceFromSun"],
  asiaPop: ["continents", "asia", "population"],
  americaArea: ["continents", "america", "area"],
  japanTemp: ["continents", "asia", "countries", "japan", "temperature"],
  foo: ["continents", "asia", "countries", "japan", "temperature", "baz"] // <~~~~ this returns null as expected
});

console.log(earthDataSubset3)
// { distanceFromSun: 149280000,
//   asiaPop: 4560667108,
//   americaArea: 42549000,
//   japanTemp: 62.5,
//   foo: null }
```

Bottom line, my question is how I could alter the current definition of `select()` to account for situations where a non-existing property could be at *any* position in that specified path, not only at the path's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your `getProp()` that's the issue – it errors when `obj` is `null` in `obj[key]`, since you cannot access properties on `null`. This happens when a top level object property does not exist on the object being `select`ed. We can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to work around this:

```typescript
const getProp = <T>(obj: any, key: string): T => obj?.[key] || null;
```

> The `?.` operator is like the `.` chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`.

```js
const is = (t, T) => t.constructor === T;
const getProp = (obj, key) => obj?.[key] || null;
const getValue = (pathToVal, origData) => pathToVal.reduce(getProp, origData);

const select = (data, paths) =>
    !is(paths, Object)
        ? new Error('path supplied not an object')
        : // else do what we want
          Object.entries(paths).reduce(
              (res, [key, path]) => Object.assign(res, { [key]: getValue(path, data) }),
              {}
          );
          
const earthData = {
  distanceFromSun: 149280000,
  continents: {
    asia: {
      area: 44579000,
      population: 4560667108,
      countries: { japan: { temperature: 62.5 } },
    },
    africa: { area: 30370000, population: 1275920972 },
    europe: { area: 10180000, population: 746419440 },
    america: { area: 42549000, population: 964920000 },
    australia: { area: 7690000, population: 25925600 },
    antarctica: { area: 14200000, population: 5000 },
  },
};

const earthDataSubset2 = select(earthData, {
  distanceFromSun: ["distanceFromSun"],
  asiaPop: ["continents", "asia", "population"],
  americaArea: ["continents", "america", "area"],
  japanTemp: ["continents", "asia", "countries", "japan", "temperature"],
  foo: ["bar", "baz"] // <~~~~ this is the addition that breaks the code
});

console.log(earthDataSubset2)
```